# Using AM-GM to find the minimum

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> Find the minimum value of $\dfrac{7x^{2} - 2xy + 3y^{2}}{x^{2} - y^{2}}$ if $x$ and $y$ are positive real numbers such that $x > y$.

This is a question from the 22nd Philippine Mathematical Olympiad. I have no idea how to solve this. I am curious as to how it was solved. Can anyone help me, please?

---

Update: I found a solution [here](https://cjquines.com/files/pmo2020quals.pdf) and it looks like it is longer than expected.

Comment: It is expected here to show your attempt at solving, so that any help provided may be useful to completing your own approach(es) and relevant to your learning.

Comment: Express in terms of $t:=\frac xy$. Optionally add the constant $3$ to simplify a term.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, I don't get the 'add the constant 3 to simplify a term'. When I used the substitution $t = \frac{x}{y}$, I just factored out $\frac{1}{y^{2}}$ on both numerator and the denominator.

Comment: Add $3$ and see.

Comment: The point is that if $f(t)$ has a minimum at $t=t_0$, then $f(t) + A$ would have a minimum at the same point for any $A$: the graph is just moved up (or down) by the amount $A$, but the shape remains the same and so does the position of the minimum. The choice $A=3$ makes the numerator simpler.

Comment: I searched for the answer of the question, and it turns out that the answer is $2 + 2\sqrt{6}$, not $5 + 2\sqrt{6}$. Is the $+3$ related to this?

Comment: $5 + 2\sqrt{6}$ is the *position* of the minimum, not the value of the function at the minimum. So you still have to substitute it in and calculate the value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let, $x=a+b$ and $y=a-b$ where $a>b$, we have

$$f(x,y)= \dfrac {2a^2+3b^2}{ab}+2$$

$$\implies \underbrace{\dfrac { 2a^2+3b^2}{ab}≥\dfrac{2\sqrt 6 ab}{ab}}_{\text{ arithmetic-geometric mean inequality}}=2 \sqrt 6$$

$$\implies \text{min} [ f(x,y)]= 2+2 \sqrt 6$$

**REMARK.**

According to equality condition of arithmetic-geometric mean inequality, we have

$$2a^2=3b^2 \Longrightarrow a= \dfrac {b\sqrt 3}{\sqrt 2}$$

which follows

$$y := b \sqrt {\dfrac {3}{2}}-b>0$$

So, conditions are hold.

Comment: Can I ask the reason behind 'Let $x = a + b$ and $y = a - b$', please?

Comment: @soupless of course, as you know for any $x,y$ there exist $a,b$ such that $x=a+b$ and $y=a-b$, Of course $a>b>0$ which follows $x>y$. Reason here is : look at the denominator. You can see that after substutition we can cancell **quadratic terms**. Of course, degree is still $2$. But, at least you could hope last expression may be very simple for to use arithmetic-geometric mean inequality.

Comment: @soupless If you have another question, please don't hesitate for ask. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: put $t= \dfrac{x}{y} \implies t > 1$. Then consider : $f(t) = \dfrac{7t^2 - 2t + 3}{t^2 - 1}, t > 1$. Can you take it from here using calculus tools ?

Comment: Apparently there's a pre-calc tag, which makes it a bit confusing as to what level this is at.  Can do without calculus, but lots more worrisome then.

Comment: For $f(t) = \frac{7t^{2} - 2t + 3}{t^{2} - 1}$, the critical points are $t = 5 \pm 2\sqrt{6}$. Since $5 - 2\sqrt{6} < 1$, then this implies that $5 + 2\sqrt{6}$ is the answer, right? Thanks for your help, though I kind of want to see how it can be solved using AM-GM inequality, if it is possible.

Comment: I think you got it right .

Answer (score 1):

**Without using calculus and arithmetic-geometric mean inequality:**

Substitute $u=\dfrac xy$ and $u>1$ then,

$$\dfrac {7u^2-2u+3}{u^2-1}=a, a>0$$

$$\implies u^2(7-a)-2u+(3+a)=0$$

$$\implies \Delta =1-(7-a)(3+a)≥0, ~ \text {where} ~0<a≠7 $$

$$\implies a≥ 2+2\sqrt 6$$

$$\implies \text {min} [a]=2+2\sqrt 6<7$$

Finally,

$$u=\dfrac {1}{5-2\sqrt 6}>1$$ which implies $x>y.$

This means, conditions are hold.

Comment: The discriminant method gives minimum  when $u\in R$ howver in this problem we have an additional constraint $u\ge 1$ which may force a sharper bound,

Answer (score 0):

$$\dfrac{7x^{2} - 2xy + 3y^{2}}{x^{2} - y^{2}}
\implies \dfrac{4 x}{x - y} + \dfrac{6 x}{x + y} - 3$$

I'm not sure this will help you but, heuristically, the minimum for $x,y>0$ always occurs when $x\approx 10y \longrightarrow min\approx 6.898989899 \quad $ If you start with any $y\in\mathbb{N}$ and step down from $10y$, you will find the minimum $x$ to begin with or you will find a point where $f(10y-n,y)$ is greater than $f(10y-(n-1),y).\quad$ At this point, the latter is the minimum $f(x,y)$.